# Returning the program to main menu

Tags: c

I want to create a program that has an option for the user to build the song (by having the user enter a duration and frequency into an array and then select option b, to play that frequency and duration). The problem I'm having is to make the program go back to the main menu correctly and have the user select an option.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    char menu, a, A, b, B, c, C;
    int duration[100];
    float frequency[100];

    printf("a. Build the song\n");
    printf("b.Play the song\n");
    printf("c. Quit\n");

    printf("Please enter an option: ");
    scanf(" %c", &menu);

    if (menu == 'a' || menu == 'A') {

        printf("Please enter a frequency: ");
        scanf("%f", &frequency[i]);
        printf("Please enter a duration: ");
        scanf("%d", &duration[i]);

        system("cls");
    }

    else if (menu == 'b' || menu == 'B') {
        Beep(frequency[i], duration[i]);
        system("cls");

        return menu;
    }
    else if (menu != 'a' || menu != 'A' && menu != 'b' || menu != 'B' && menu != 'c' || menu != 'C') {
        while (menu != 'a' || menu != 'A' && menu != 'b' || menu != 'B' && menu != 'c' || menu != 'C') {

            printf("\n\nSorry that an invalid input\n\n");
            printf("a. Build the song\n");
            printf("b.Play the song\n");
            printf("c. Quit\n");

            printf("Please enter an option: ");
            scanf(" %c", &menu);
        }
    }
    else if (menu == 'c' || menu == 'C') {
        return 0;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: You need a loop.

Comment: Isnt it possible without a loop?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a loop? It's a fairly straightforward solution to your problem.

Comment: So, what loop would be the most appropriate for this code? a WHILE LOOP?

Comment: There's not a lot of point in choosing option b until you've used option a.  You need a loop to iterate until the user chooses option c, do you not?  And that would probably be a `while` loop that calls a function that posts the menu and reads the answer — you'll need to move some code around, and create functions.  Creating functions is a good idea anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the code that you need to use again inside a loop. A `while` loop with a check variable (you already have that) is all you need.

example:

```
// print menu
// get input
// check if input is valid
while(menu != 'c')
{
    //your code here

     // print menu
    // get input
   // check if input is valid
}
```

Comment: Oh okay, Thank you!

Comment: @Deval Rajgor_109 if my anwer helped you please accept it.

Comment: Oh okay, srry, I forgot to do it